# Do we always have min/max with $x=y=z$ for symmetric function and constraint?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Symmetric function means that $f(x,y,z)=f(x,z,y)=f(y,x,z)=...$

For example, let $f(x)=xyz$ and $g(x)=x+y+z$ where $g(x)=1$ is the constraint and $x,y,z\geq 0$ for simplicity. Both $f$ and $g$ are symmetric.

Then we have

min at:$(0,0,1) (0,1,0) (1,0,0)$

max at:$(1/3,1/3,1/3)\leftarrow x=y=z$

Suppose there is at least one max/min solution for the function and constraint. I want to know that do we always have at least one min/max with $x=y=z$ for symmetric function and constraint? Any proof or disproof? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with a function with no extrema at all, say $x+y+z$, then add [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) that peak at $(2,0,0)$, $(0,2,0)$, and $(0,0,2)$, the result will be symmetric and only have extrema off the line $x=y=z$.  You could always rig the problem so that with the constraint your extrema are on that line though.  For instance if the constraint was $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$.